# Assigning dictionary keys from a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, mutable

I am attempting to create a directed graph as described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-graph-using-dictionary-python/

However, when i attempt to create nodes with a for loop, at the end i am left with ALL nodes of the same type (that are created using the for loop) being THE LAST ONE that was created, despite the expected behaviour of that not being the case...

I have tried using `copy.deepcopy` of a node when assigning to dictionary however that ends up with being unable to add more than 1 edge to each node

```
class GraphNode
    def __init__(self,
                 node_type: str,
                 node_id: str,
                 position: GraphNodePosition):
        self.parameters = self.generate_empty_parameters(node_type)
        self.type = node_type
        self.id = node_id
        self.position = position

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.type != other.type:
            return False
        if self.parameters != other.parameters:
            return False
        return True

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

class ApplicationGraph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes: typing.DefaultDict[GraphNode, typing.List[GraphNode]] = collections.defaultdict(list)

    def add_new_node(self, node: GraphNode) -> bool:
        if node not in self.nodes.keys():
            self.nodes[node] = list()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def add_new_edge(self, source_node: GraphNode, destination_node: GraphNode) -> bool:
        if source_node not in self.nodes.keys():
            return False
        else:
            self.nodes[source_node].append(destination_node)
            return True
```

expected:

```
for created_node in node_list:
    graph.add_new_node(created_node["node"])
    for created_edge in created_node["edges"]:
        graph.add_new_edge(created_node["node"],
```

graph would be like this:

```
{
    node1: [node2, node3],
    node2: [node3],
    node3: []
}
```

actual:

graph ends up being like this:

```
{
    node3: []
}
```

EDIT 1: i am 100% certain that self.id is unique for every for loop assignment

EDIT 2:

```
node_list: typing.List(dict) = [
    {
        "node": GraphNode object,
        "edges": [GraphNode objects this node is connected to]
    }
]
```

EDIT 3:

each node is created like this:

```
arguments_for_id: typing.Dict[str, str]
arguments_for_node: typing.Dict[str, typing.Union[str, int, bool, float, list, dict]
foo_node = GraphNode(
    node_type="foo",
    node_id=GraphNode.generate_id(
        node_type="foo",
        **arguments_for_id
    ),
    position=GraphNodePosition(
        x=x_position,
        y=y_position
    )
)
# arguments_for_id are a subset of arguments_for_node
for argument_name, argument_value in arguments_for_node.items():
    getattr(foo_node.parameters, argument_name).value = argument_value
```

EDIT 4: added typing descriptions for `arguments_for_id` and `arguments_for_node`

EDIT 5: `generate_id` function

```
def generate_id(node_type: str, **kwargs) -> str:
    invalid_id = f"%INVALIDID%KWARGS:{kwargs}"
    if node_type not in GraphNode.required_node_id_parameters.keys():
        return invalid_id
    elif not list(kwargs.keys()) == GraphNode.required_node_id_parameters[node_type]:
        return invalid_id
    else:
        result = f"{node_type}"
        for parameter_name, parameter_value in kwargs.items():
            result += f"_{parameter_value}"
        return result
```

EDIT 6: minimum code required to replicate the problem

```
a = Application("foobar")

l3out_node = GraphNode(
    node_type="l3out",
    node_id=GraphNode.generate_id(
        node_type="l3out",
        application_name="foobar"
    ),
    position=GraphNodePosition(
        x=0,
        y=0
    )
)
l3out_node.parameters.application_name.value = "foobar"

a.graph.add_new_node(l3out_node)

tier_nodes = [
    GraphNode(
        node_type="tier",
        node_id=GraphNode.generate_id(
            node_type="tier",
            application_name="foobar",
            tier_name="foo"
        ),
        position=GraphNodePosition(
            x=100,
            y=100
        )
    ),
    GraphNode(
        node_type="tier",
        node_id=GraphNode.generate_id(
            node_type="tier",
            application_name="foobar",
            tier_name="bar"
        ),
        position=GraphNodePosition(
            x=100,
            y=-100
        )
    ),
]

tier_nodes[0].parameters.application_name.value = "foobar"
tier_nodes[0].parameters.tier_name.value = "foo"
tier_nodes[1].parameters.application_name.value = "foobar"
tier_nodes[1].parameters.tier_name.value = "bar"

for tier_node in tier_nodes:
    a.graph.add_new_node(tier_node)
    a.graph.add_new_edge(l3out_node, tier_node)

print(a)
print(a.graph.edges)
```

output:

`a`:

```
{"name": "foobar","graph": {"nodes": [{"type": "l3out","position": {"x":0,"y":0},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"}}}, {"type": "tier","position": {"x":100,"y":100},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"},"tier_name":{"name": "tier_name","value": "bar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime nivoja"},"hypervisor":{"name": "hypervisor","value": "","is_required": true,"description": "Kateri hypervisor je pripet na ta nivo (vse virtualke na tem nivoju bodo narejene na tem hypervisorju"}}}, {"type": "tier","position": {"x":100,"y":-100},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"},"tier_name":{"name": "tier_name","value": "bar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime nivoja"},"hypervisor":{"name": "hypervisor","value": "","is_required": true,"description": "Kateri hypervisor je pripet na ta nivo (vse virtualke na tem nivoju bodo narejene na tem hypervisorju"}}}],"edges": [{"source": {"type": "l3out","position": {"x":0,"y":0},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"}}}, "destination": {"type": "tier","position": {"x":100,"y":100},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"},"tier_name":{"name": "tier_name","value": "bar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime nivoja"},"hypervisor":{"name": "hypervisor","value": "","is_required": true,"description": "Kateri hypervisor je pripet na ta nivo (vse virtualke na tem nivoju bodo narejene na tem hypervisorju"}}}}, {"source": {"type": "l3out","position": {"x":0,"y":0},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"}}}, "destination": {"type": "tier","position": {"x":100,"y":-100},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"},"tier_name":{"name": "tier_name","value": "bar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime nivoja"},"hypervisor":{"name": "hypervisor","value": "","is_required": true,"description": "Kateri hypervisor je pripet na ta nivo (vse virtualke na tem nivoju bodo narejene na tem hypervisorju"}}}}]}}
```

`a.graph.edges`:

```
[{'source': {"type": "l3out","position": {"x":0,"y":0},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"}}}, 'destination': {"type": "tier","position": {"x":100,"y":100},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"},"tier_name":{"name": "tier_name","value": "bar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime nivoja"},"hypervisor":{"name": "hypervisor","value": "","is_required": true,"description": "Kateri hypervisor je pripet na ta nivo (vse virtualke na tem nivoju bodo narejene na tem hypervisorju"}}}}, {'source': {"type": "l3out","position": {"x":0,"y":0},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"}}}, 'destination': {"type": "tier","position": {"x":100,"y":-100},"parameters": {"application_name":{"name": "application_name","value": "foobar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime aplikacije"},"tier_name":{"name": "tier_name","value": "bar","is_required": true,"description": "Ime nivoja"},"hypervisor":{"name": "hypervisor","value": "","is_required": true,"description": "Kateri hypervisor je pripet na ta nivo (vse virtualke na tem nivoju bodo narejene na tem hypervisorju"}}}}]
```

the crux of the problem is that the destination tiers should be "foo" and "bar" but are "bar" in both cases

Comment: i've edited my opening post with the node list description @DeveshKumarSingh, when i print id for each node in node_list, they are different and are exactly as expected. the final result, however, only has the final (`node_list[-1]`) node as a key in the dictionary

Comment: i've added a concrete example as well (i can't show actual code, the create_empty_parameters is implemented to define the real cases) @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: i've added a typing description for `arguments_for_id` and `arguments_for_node` @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: I've added a minimal example illustrating the problem